# Do AS3 comments get compiled?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

Easy question.

Does the code between comment tags get compiled?

```
// I'm a comment
/* I'm another comment */
```

Comment: I don't see why they would get compiled

Comment: Yea I agree, but I haven't been able to find any reference to this, and I'd like to know the answer to the question.

Comment: I vaguely remember reading that in Essential Action Script 3.0 by Colin Moock. So far I've only got very cumbersome ideas: compile the above code into a swf, then decompile it or run through the [byte code](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/actionscript/articles/avm2overview.pdf). You could actually code that in a separate as3 script using the as3swf or as3-commons libraries. Another option would be looking at the actionscript compiler source code

Comment: Does ANY compiler, anywhere compile comments?  Doesn't make sense. Comments are for people, compiled code is for machines.

Comment: @Craig if you are so sure of that please provide evidence in an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Thanks for your offer, but Profenza has already suggested a way for you to provide your own evidence. Actually here's an easier way: make a small test swf. Then add a few hundred (or thousand) lines of commented strings. Remake the swf and compare sizes. When you find out that I'm right mark this as correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the proof.

[image]

I created an empty project and compiled it twice. One was the bare minimum (I compiled immediately after creation) and the other had ~2000 comments. The comments were a mix of the following:

```
/**
 * This is a comment
 */

// this is a comment

/*
    This is a comment
*/
```

Repeated a few hundred times each, the Main.as file jumped from 134 bytes to 32KB. This most definitely should have raised the final size of the SWF if the comments had been included. Instead, they were both *exactly* the same size, at 608 bytes (a fraction of the total size of the code in the file with the comments).

So, as logic would tell you, no, the compiler does not include comments.